# Is there an Ubuntu version designed for children?

Tags: 16.04

Do you all have a OS specially made for kids and how much does it cost? And do you all have a book that teaches how to use Ubuntu 16.04 and if so how much for it?

Comment: We are community site, so there's no books for purchase here. Kids version also doesn't exist. What exactly you're looking for ?

Comment: The closest for kids that I can think of is [Edubuntu](https://www.edubuntu.org/) which is free.  There are books online you can look for or try local bookstores or libraries.

Comment: just use regular ubuntu, the buttons are big, are there are lots of games and stuff in the ubuntu software app, the OS is free, all you need to do is install some kid specific apps, like tux paint, pySioGame, and some games

Comment: Perhaps you can explain what specifically you mean by "designed for children".  There are many different definitions for what could be "designed for children", so more specifics on what you are asking will get you better or more targeted answers.

Comment: @ThomasWard https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Edubuntu/AppGuide takes care of that. ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind I think you missed the point of my question  to the OP.  They may have different intent when asking for a children oriented OS, hence the initial inquiry

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer me. I found puppy Linux but it wont install. on computers. so I thought maybe their would be an OS for kids that will install on computers. I been learning how to fix computers for about 2 years now and been in college  for 81/2 months learning computers. I have about 20 PC's and some of them I fixed just for kids. and like I said puppy Linux wont install. so I thought I would find out if their is other OS designed for kids like puppy Linux that will install on a PC.

Answer (score 6):

All Ubuntu versions are free of charge and the educational version of Ubuntu is called [Edubuntu](https://www.edubuntu.org/).

[image]

> **What is Edubuntu?**
>
> The Edubuntu Project
>
> Edubuntu is a grassroots movement, we aim to get Ubuntu into schools, homes and communities and make it easy for users to install and maintain their systems.
>
> We are students, teachers, parents and hackers who believe that learning and knowledge should be available to everyone who wants to improve themselves and the world around them.

The [screenshot tour](https://www.edubuntu.org/screenshots) gives an impression of what is included. You can see basic colorful games and software oriented to teaching about space.

---

Edubuntu is having problems though so the 14.04 might be its final release. [There will be no 16.04](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Edubuntu-16.04). On the other hand ... Edubuntu is Ubuntu with some packages oriented to kids. Here is a [list of packages](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Edubuntu/AppGuide) in Edubuntu divided into a school type set (pre-school, secondary and tertiary). Add those to a normal Ubuntu and you are good to go.